# Windows 8 tablet does not display TabTip (on-screen keyboard) on top of Qt OpenGL application

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, windows-8, tablet

I have a full screen QT OpenGL application which needs to display the virtual keyboard (tabTip.exe) when input textboxes are entered. The problem I'm facing is that the virtual keyboard appears behind the application when the keyboard is invoked. I have tried many different things and found that the only way I can make it appear in front, is if my window is not fullscreen (e.g. making it 1 pixel less than full screen in the width and/or height). If I have the tablet in portrait mode this also still displays the keyboard even in full screen.

Now I'm trying to figure out if this is a driver issue, Qt issue, OpenGL issue or general windows issue.

Any suggestions?

**Update:**

I have investigated this a bit further and I think I see what's going on.
Windows 8, upon detecting that the monitor rotation is set to zero, and that it has an OpenGL window that matches the desktop resolution and covers the whole screen, kicks into legacy mode that blocks any Windows 8 themed animations from running (including virtual keyboard). 
Do you have any suggestions on how I can stop windows from doing this? DwmEnableComposition has been removed in windows 8.

Comment: this is really interesting but I have no idea how to fix it :/

Comment: Yes indeed, I have tried all manner of different things in the last 2 days but I'm still convinced there is a way to make this work properly.

Comment: make the window one pixel larger (preferably -- if that works), or smaller, than the screen to fool the logic! :)